# MYSQL Insert создает две строчки

Tags: php, mysql

Отправляю некоторые данные с помощью PHP на ДБ.

Код вроде простой - но строчки создаются парные, причем, что удивительно - две переменных отображаются на одной строке, остальные на второй.

Код:

```
<?php
// Check connection
    if($link === false)
    {
        die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

// Escape user inputs for security
$first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['FirstName']);
$last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['LastName']);
$start_adress = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['stadres']);
$end_adress = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['endadres']);
$Price = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['price_finalized']);
$CarriersQuant = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['amount_of_carriers']);


// Attempt insert query execution
$post = "INSERT INTO Orders (FirstName, LastName, StartAdress, EndAdress, Price, CarriersQuant) VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$start_adress', '$end_adress', '$Price', '$CarriersQuant')";

if(mysqli_query($link, $post))
{
    echo "Records added successfully.";
} else  
{
echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $post. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
```

Вот как это выглядит в ДБ:
[image: Скриншот из ДБ]

Ума не приложу, где может быть ошибка.

Comment: `print_r($post)` покажите.